# Browse pages urls within netbeans 7.3

Tags: netbeans, web-deployment

I am working in a web project using Netbeans IDE but when I deploy the application and browse it in some browser (`Google Chrome` or `Firefox` or ...) I navigate from the Netbeans program to the browser in this situation will be very tired.

So I want to open a new tab within the Netbeans and open the deployed URL inside it, For fast browsing, viweing and testing, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans has so called embedded browser. I don't know the project type you are using, but you can set in Tools->Options default browser to be "Embedded browser" and it whenever IDE is about to open some browser, it will use this one and it will open inside NetBeans. If you are using HTML/JavaScript project type, you can change browser by the combo box in main toolbar, again to Embedded browser.

Comment: I found better than `IDE Default Browser` is using plugin from [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38508/), for more feature.